# How to open a file given in input in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project and for this I need to open a file. So for this I wanted to use `open("my_file", "r")` but the problem is that the name of the file is dynamic, it could be toto.txt or jziop.txt I no matter how the user will call it. I know in `C` I would just use `open` with the `av[1]` but is it possible in `python` ? I'm new in it so I'm learning.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the name of the file is dynamic"?

Comment: Use `sys.argv[1]`. Command line arguments can be accessed from `sts.argv[]` array.

Comment: It's not always the same name, the user can input a .txt file with a total random name.

Comment: you already have the answer from comments `fname = sys.argv[1]` - just use it

Comment: open() can be passed a string variable

Comment: `sys.argv[1]`! hear me?

Comment: yes thank you, do I have to stock it in a variable or I can just put it in my open() ?

Comment: @hissroth, ask your heart, what does it saying to you ...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that is wrong english and what if he does being a robot without a heart? xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
# do stuff
f.close()
```

This will read the first argument and place it as the filename.

Comment: Personally i wouldn't still a code from the comments.

Comment: Let's show some dignity and not post a ready answers from comments

Comment: @u Isn't good that some actually writes some answer that can be voted up or down? The answer could be improved with an explanation or reference but at least it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you `import sys` (a built-in module), you will have access to the `sys.argv` variable, a list holding all arguments passed into your program.

The first argument `sys.argv[0]` is the path to your program, so you actually want the second argument `sys.argv[1]`

```
python  my_script.py  my_file.txt
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~  ^~~~~~~~~~~
        sys.argv[0]   sys.argv[1]
```

Final code snippet:

```
import sys

assert len(sys.argv) >= 2

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  data = f.read()
```